# Seals that form around a moving (linear) rectangular object

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am looking to find a seal like the one in the image that seals around the outside of a rectangular object and allows it to move, but when I search "square seal" I just get round o-rings that have a square cross section. Can anyone tell me what I need to search for to find such a seal as the one in the picture?

[image: Square rubber seal]

It is to be used so that the glass in the picture below can be moved forward and back through the container holding a liquid.

[image: Container assembly]

Comment: It would help if you could give an indication of scale

Comment: So the glass plate you can see there is 210x250mm by 6mm thick. It will move back and forth with a stroke of 120mm.

Comment: It is extremely difficult to create a good seal at any sort of sharp corner, let alone one that has to slide as well. What exactly is accomplished by moving the glass back and forth that can't be satisfied by simply making the tank larger?

Comment: Could you not just round the edges of the glass and then use a normal o-ring? As it has been previously said - it's very hard to get a seal around square corners.

Comment: The glass is fused silica and comes in sheets with square edges but I guess I may be able to have them machined somehow to have round edges. The concept is for our 3D printers and is a bit too detailed to explain all on here but the sliding glass feature is crucial to the machines function so can't be changed unfortunately. The only option I have is to try and form a seal somehow. My concern with using a normal o-ring was that the radius at the corners would be much smaller than designed if it were to also fit over the entire glass plate, which I thought may not form a proper seal